# Getting does not provide an export named 'default' in my React project

Tags: reactjs

I am using an opensource react project and getting the following error.

```
does not provide an export named  'default'
```

Here is the .js file causing the issue.

```
import { RevAiStreamingClient, AudioConfig } from 'revai-node-sdk';

module.exports = class StreamingClient {
  constructor(accessToken, io) {
    console.log('Loading Streaming Client');
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.io = io;
  }

  start() {
    this.revAiStreamingClient = new RevAiStreamingClient(this.accessToken, new AudioConfig('audio/x-wav'));

    this.revAiStreamingClient.on('close', (code, reason) => {
      console.log(`Connection closed, ${code}: ${reason}`);
    });

    this.revAiStreamingClient.on('httpResponse', (code) => {
      console.log(`Streaming client received http response with code: ${code}`);
    });

    this.revAiStreamingClient.on('connectFailed', (error) => {
      console.log(`Connection failed with error: ${error}`);
    });

    this.revAiStreamingClient.on('connect', (connectionMessage) => {
      console.log(`Connected with job id: ${connectionMessage.id}`);
      this.io.emit('streaming-connected', connectionMessage);
    });

    this.revStream = this.revAiStreamingClient.start();
    this.revStream.on('data', (data) => {
      this.io.emit('transcript', data);
    });
  }

  end() {
    this.revStream = null;
    this.revAiStreamingClient.end();
  }

  stream(data) {
    console.log('streaming data ....');
    this.revStream && this.revStream.write(data);
  }
};
```

UPDATE:

Fixed it.

```
import { RevAiStreamingClient, AudioConfig } from 'revai-node-sdk';

class StreamingClient {
  constructor(accessToken, io) {
    console.log('Loading Streaming Client');
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.io = io;
  }

  start() {
    this.revAiStreamingClient = new RevAiStreamingClient(this.accessToken, new AudioConfig('audio/x-wav'));

    this.revAiStreamingClient.on('close', (code, reason) => {
      console.log(`Connection closed, ${code}: ${reason}`);
    });

    this.revAiStreamingClient.on('httpResponse', (code) => {
      console.log(`Streaming client received http response with code: ${code}`);
    });

    this.revAiStreamingClient.on('connectFailed', (error) => {
      console.log(`Connection failed with error: ${error}`);
    });

    this.revAiStreamingClient.on('connect', (connectionMessage) => {
      console.log(`Connected with job id: ${connectionMessage.id}`);
      this.io.emit('streaming-connected', connectionMessage);
    });

    this.revStream = this.revAiStreamingClient.start();
    this.revStream.on('data', (data) => {
      this.io.emit('transcript', data);
    });
  }

  end() {
    this.revStream = null;
    this.revAiStreamingClient.end();
  }

  stream(data) {
    console.log('streaming data ....');
    this.revStream && this.revStream.write(data);
  }
}

export default StreamingClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to see more of the error message to understand but best guess is that somewhere in your code it says export default instead of export default insert component name.